# UWP VAPID alternate channels 401

Tags: javascript, uwp, web-push, vapid

I'm trying to use [alternate channels](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/shell/tiles-and-notifications/alternate-channel-vapid-webpush) to deliver push notifications to my UWP app. So far, I've got the URI and I've tried to send the push notification using both cURL and pywebpush, but I get a 401 in both cases. I'm using the JS API to get the channel like this:

```js
const pnm = Windows.Networking.PushNotifications.PushNotificationChannelManager.getDefault();
const writer = new Windows.Storage.Streams.DataWriter();
writer.writeString(environment.VAPID_PUBLIC_KEY);
const buffer = writer.detachBuffer();

const notifPromise = pnm.createRawPushNotificationChannelWithAlternateKeyForApplicationAsync(buffer, 'notif');
notifPromise.done(subscription => {
    console.log(subscription);
    subscription.addEventListener('pushnotificationreceived', message => {
        console.log(message);
    });
}
```

The cURL request returns as

```
* upload completely sent off: 5 out of 5 bytes
< HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
< Content-Length: 0
< X-WNS-MSG-ID: 1FFF6A946F1C84F4
< X-WNS-DEBUG-TRACE: SG2PEPF00000441
< MS-CV: npI4XUfCt0m9QBptzatEnQ.0
< Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains
< WWW-Authenticate: bearer error="invalid_request",error_description="Invalid token"
< Date: Sun, 24 Feb 2019 08:21:00 GMT
```

where my URI looks like `https://sg2p.notify.windows.com/w/?token=BIG_TOKEN` and I've the `Authorization`, `TTL` and `Crypto-Key` headers added.

I'm using webpush for notifying browsers and it works fine. Any idea what could be wrong here?

Comment: Please check this line `WWW-Authenticate: bearer error="invalid_request",error_description="Invalid token"`, It looks you used wrong token.

Comment: @NicoZhuMSFT of course I checked that. It displays the same error even if I send wrong headers to an edge webpush endpoint, so it doesn't seem very useful